# Centering image within box with content below

Tags: html, css, image, center, centering

I'm currently building this box, witch must be responsive. But the image below 768px resolution have the same resolution.

I can center the image (In this example is just a square), but I want with content below, but with this method, adding position: absolute to `<img>` (Ex: div) the `<p>` element will be absolute too..

How can I float `<p>` below the image?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luisserrano/SmBXR/)

Comment: So you are trying to have a div that is centered, and a paragraph right under it?

Answer (score 0):

Use this css instead:

```
.container-center > div {
    width: 270px;
    height: 188px;
    background-color: green;
    /*Centering*/
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SmBXR/1/

Comment: This is working fine in the fiddle but in reality this isn't working. Still the same.

Comment: I'm using bootstrap. So the container is a row-fluid

Comment: I can only answer your question based on the code you have given. If its different code on your site then you should show that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This will centre the text below the green box.

```
.container {
border: 1px solid black;
}

.container p {
position: relative;
margin: 0px auto;
text-align:center;
}

.container-center > div {
width: 270px;
height: 188px;
background-color: green;
position: relative;
/*Centering*/
margin: 0px 0 0 -135px;
left: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Are you referring to your live environment or the fiddle?  Check out the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SmBXR/3/

Comment: To my live environment.

Comment: works in the example, it's hard to know what you have going on in your live environment. Would it be possible to get a link?

Comment: No.. This is a big project I'm redesign, so.. I can't show a live version.

Comment: But this is a block with an image in and a title and text below. When we resize below 768px, all text goes under the image (before, they was aligned horizontally) and the image must stay at center after that.